# If $XY$ is diameter, $PR\perp XY$..

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $XY$ is the diameter, $PR\perp XY$ and $PC\perp XQ$ then prove that $2AB=QR$.

[image]

My Attempt

1. $P,X,A and C$ are Concyclic points.
   So, $PXAC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
2. $\angle XPA=\angle XCA$
3. $AP=AR$

Now how should I move further? 
Please help.

Comment: We can assume B is the point of intersection of line AC with line PQ.  Neither A nor C are mentioned either but it is clear from the diagram they are the point of intersection of the perpendicular with the bases.

Comment: If you can show withe AB is parellel to RQ or that PB = QB then it follows from similar triangles.

Comment: I don't know but ivd start with trying to assign values/relations between evert angle I could.  I imagine I'd be able to deduce PRQ =PAB and that'd be sufficient.

Comment: I'm assuming QR is not supposed to be a diameter.

Comment: Here is a dynamic GeoGebra diagram of the exercise: http://ggbm.at/fJFc7kbT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, $P$, $X$, $A$ and $C$ are concyclic points, so that:
$$
\angle BCQ=\angle XCA=\angle XPA=\angle XRP=\angle XQP.
$$
It follows that $CBQ$ is isosceles and, as $PC\perp CQ$, $CBP$ is isosceles too, so that $B$ is the midpoint of $PQ$.

Line $AB$ joins the midpoints of two sides of triangle $PQR$, so we have [by well-known theorems](http://users.humboldt.edu/flashman/mdptthrm.html) $AB\parallel QR$ and $AB={1\over2} QR$.

Comment: how is $\triangle CBP$ an isosceles triangle?    Also, how is $\angle XPA=\angle XRP$?

Comment: Let $\angle BQC=\angle BCQ=\alpha$. Then $\angle PCB=\pi/2-\alpha$ and $\angle BPC=\pi/2-\alpha$, so triangle $CBP$ is isosceles. Line $AX$ is the perpendicular bisector of $PR$, so $XP=XR$ and $\angle XPR=\angle XRP$.